# Dropdown list created from a list in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-data-validation

Is it possible to create a dropdown list from only one cell as a source? Each element separated by commas?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible via Data Validation. You can either use **List of items** mod where you enter your comma separated values directly, or you can use **List from a range** mod where each dropdown item needs to be in a separate cell.

A workaround would be to have your one cell with CSV items as you wish to, and then secretly deploy that one cell into a range and feed your Data Validation from that range referencing your one cell. Something like this:

[image: 0]

**A1:** dropdown
**C1:** comma separated values in one cell
**E1:** **`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C1, ","))`**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a built-in Google Sheets web app feature but by using Google Apps Script it's possible. To learn the basics, please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets